# Ruby on Rails Active Record - Search with multiple arguments using IN condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My data structure looks like:

```
User.first.department
=> "devops maintaining staff"

User.second.department
=> "facility staff"
```

I'm searching for a *search query* which does a search with **single** or **multiple arguments** for example:

- search with *single argument*

  ```
  "staff"                # which should return both users
  ```
- search with *multiple arguments*

  ```
  "maintaining devops"   # which should return first user
  ```
- search with *single argument*

  ```
  "maintaining"          # which should return first user
  ```
- another search with *single argument*

  ```
  "facility"             # which should return second user
  ```

Is there any useful example how to accomplish this?

Comment: What's your database?

Comment: I'm using SQLite in development and MySQL in production

Comment: Are you looking for exact match or fuzzy? That's going to really change the answer for your question.

Comment: doesn't matter, simple solution is welcome

Comment: Have you considered redesigning your database tables structure? Seems like you are embedding a N:M relationship in a single string field. There could be some reasons to do this, but in general it is discouraged (it causes issues like this one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you're asking for sounds like substring matching. My answer is a "brute force" style of querying and it will become brittle / fall apart really quickly in real-world usage:

```
# keywords is an array of strings
def keyword_search(keywords)
  query = User

  keywords.each do |keyword|
    query = query.where('department like ?', "%#{keyword}%")
  end

  query.to_a
end
```

So for your examples you'd get the following queries:

```
# Returns both users for "staff" 
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (department like '%staff%')

# Returns first user for "maintaining devops"
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (department like '%maintaining%') AND (department like '%devops%')

# Returns first user for "maintaining devops"
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (department like '%maintaining%') 

# Returns first users for "facility"
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (department like '%facility%')
```

Notice for this type of solution, it's an `AND` query, so all the keywords will have to match to get a result. The `%` sign in the query makes the query slightly fuzzier, so for `%staff%` you'd get matches for the following:

- `staff`
- `staffroom`
- `flagstaffs`
- `overstaff`

Which you can adjust by dropping the `%`s if you're looking for more exact matches.

---

As [Eric suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41926115/33226), anything more complicated than this is going to require a more advanced solution.

Personally I've used `Solr/Websolr` and have had good success with it, but the query and search tuning takes a bit of work to understand and implement.

Comment: Is it possible to make a search query which matches for all these 4 examples?

Comment: @StefHej It does. Did you try the code out? How'd you test that it's not working?

Comment: yes it *connects* each keywords with `AND`. Is there a way to do this with `OR`?

Comment: @StefHej your question does have any cases that requires an `OR` predicate. The above code could be modified to use `OR` clauses with rails' `or` statement: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32753177/33226

Comment: Ok, I'll try this out. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need [full-text search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html), which is database dependent.

Here's a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147827/full-text-mysql-search-in-rails). For anything more advanced, you might want to look at [sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/about/sphinx/) and [thinking-sphinx](https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx).